# Escaping from castle TypeScript: enum hell when a string key can be undefined

Tags: typescript, enums, undefined

How do I map a string to a Typescript enum value with a default failover? Given the following TypeScript enum,

```
export enum Environment {
    dev = 'dev',
    test = 'test',
    prod = 'prod',
}
```

I can't cleanly cast it to an enum with `Environment[process.env.NODE_ENV]` because the env var could be `undefined`. If it is, I simply want to failover to the `Environment.test`.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

- Try to constrain the input type:

```
let envName: string = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== undefined) ? process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() : 'test';
let env = Environment[envName];
```

Perhaps, this is a problem with Jest, but it throws:

```
TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    backend/lib/config.ts:23:19 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof Environment'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof Environment'.

    23 let environment = Environment[envName];
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

- Iterate over the keys:

```
export function mapEnum(e: any): Array<{ key: string, value: number }> {
    // annoying helper to coerce string to enum.
    return Object.keys(e)
        .map((key) => e[key])
        .filter((key) => typeof key === "string")
        .map((key) => {
            return {
                key,
                value: e[key],
            };
        });
}

let filtered: any = mapEnum(Environment)
    .filter((e) => e.key.toLowerCase() === envName);

let environment = (filtered.length === 1) ? Environment[filtered[0].key] : Environment.test;
```

Comment: with the first method you tried, what is the value of env ? because it worked for me as expected

Comment: @user007 Updated question with the exception I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source of my woes was a "diagnostic" flag I had to set to false in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': { diagnostics: false }, // this fixed it
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: i was about to write that you may need to check your configuration files. Glad you sorted it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

for your first solution:

```
let envName: Environment = ((process.env.NODE_ENV !== undefined) ? process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() : 'test') as Environment;
let env = Environment[envName];
```

your `envName` was simply a string, and you tried to index access `Environment` enum with a string, which of course is not type-safe